# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Error al hacer la tercera tabla relacional, no puede añadir la clave foránea

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Hola gente al hacer foreign key de dos campos me salta ese error, tengo dos bases de datos que son

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSpecialtyUserTable extends Migration
{
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up(){
Schema::create('specialty_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    //dentista
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
    //especialidad del dentista
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('specialty_id');

    $table->foreign('specialty_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('specialities')
    ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
 });
}

 /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function down()
  {
  // DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
  Schema::table('specialty_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('user_id');
    $table->dropForeign('specialty_id');
  });
  Schema::dropIfExists('specialty_user');
  // DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

 }
}
```

Esa es en la que relaciono las dos tablas que relaciona usuarios con especialidades, su relación es de muchos a muchos

Y la primera tabla es esta que se encarga de almacenar las especialidades de los usuarios

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

 class CreateSpecialitiesTable extends Migration
 {
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
{ 
Schema::create('specialities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('descripcion')->nullable();
    $table->date('fecha')->nullable();
    $table->integer('piezas')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
}

/**
* Reverse the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function down()
{
Schema::dropIfExists('specialities');
}
}
```

La segunda tabla es esta que se encarga de crear usuarios con sus siguientes campos descritos a continuacion

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
 public function up()
 {
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('direccionDentista')->nullable();
    $table->string('telefonoDentista')->nullable();
    $table->string('role');
    $table->string('dni')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
  }); 
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {

   Schema::dropIfExists('users');
   }
 }
```

en el controlador tengo el siguiente codigo que se encarga de recoger los datos y enviarlos a la vista correspondiente para mostrarlo

```
  /**
  * funcion que guarda la informacion de un dentista creado
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request recibe los datos de un dentista creado
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
  //dd($request->all());
  $reglas = [
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'dni' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{7,8}[A-Z]$/i',
    'direccionDentista' => 'nullable|min:6',
    'telefonoDentista' => 'required',
   ];
   $avisos = [
    'name.required' => 'El nombre del dentista es obligatorio',
    'name.min' => 'El nombre dentista debe tener más de 3 caracteres',
    'direccion.min' => 'La direccion del dentista debe tener más de 6 caracteres',
    'email.required' => 'El correo electronico del dentista es obligatorio',
    'email.email' => 'Ingresa una direccion de correo electronico valido',
    'dni.required' => 'El dni del dentista es obligatorio',
    'dni.regex' => 'La celula debe tener 8 digitos y un caracter',
    'telefonoDentista.required' => 'El telefono del dentista es obligatorio',
  ];
  $this->validate($request, $reglas, $avisos);

  $user= User::create(
    $request->only('name', 'email', 'dni', 'telefonoDentista', 'direccionDentista')
        + [
            'role' => 'dentista',
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
        ]
   );

   $user->especialidades()->attach($request->input("especialidades"));
   $notificacion = 'El dentista se a creado correctamente';
   return redirect('/dentistas')->with(compact('notificacion'));
  }
```

Antes de hacer la relación todo funciona perfectamente, pero después cuando hago la relación y ejecuta un php artisan migrate:refresh --seed me salta ese error, entonces no entiendo el porque de ese error

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent 
 row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `users`)
```

El error que me da cuando hago un php artisan migrate:fresh es el siguiente

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table 
`specialty_user` add constraint `specialty_user_specialty_id_foreign` foreign key 
(`specialty_id`) references `specialities` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Comment: el primer error indica que no puedes eliminar un registro que esta associado mediante claves foraneas osea que estas utilizando ese id como clave foranea en otro lado... entonces no puedes ni cambiar el ID ni borrarlo.

Comment: el segundo error indica que estas intentando hacer un delete, mismo problema que el anterior pero en una cascada al intentar alterar algo ...

Comment: ahora no entiendo por que motivo estas creando tablas desde el codigo ... por ejemplo en synfony te permite crear las entidades y actualizar tu esquema desde la consola ... evitando este tipo de errores... el diseño DD de tu base de datos debes hacerlo antes de que comiences a escribir codigo y por lo menos un diagrama de flujo de como van a ocurrir los eventos te ayudaria al diseño de tu base de datos.